# How to get an array of maximum values between two arrays

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for an elegant way of getting an array containing the maximum values between two arrays.

Meaning if there are two arrays:

```
a = [1, 5, 9]
b = [3, 2, 11]
```

The result should be:

```
=> [3, 5, 11]
```

Assume both arrays are of the same size.

The code I use doesn't feel like a Ruby way to do that task:

```
c = Array.new(a.size)
for i in 0...a.size
  c[i] = [a[i], b[i]].max
end
```

Comment: why not *9,5,..* ? *maximum values between two arrays* what's the logic?

Comment: @Babai it's the element-wise maximum

Comment: Why not show the code you've written, to let us know you've tried to find an answer on your own? That's the Stack Overflow way. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work:

```
[a, b].transpose.map(&:max)
#=> [3, 5, 11]
```

`transpose` returns `[[1, 3], [5, 2], [9, 11]]` and `map(&:max)` finds each sub array's maximum.

`a.zip(b)` (as suggested by Abe Voelker) is equivalent to `[a, b].transpose` if both arrays have the same number of elements. If element size differs, `transpose` would raise an exception:

```
[1].zip([2,3])
#=> [[1,2]]

[[1], [2,3]].transpose
#=> IndexError: element size differs
```

### Benchmarks

```
require 'benchmark'

a = (1..1000).to_a
b = a.reverse

n = 1000
Benchmark.bm(10) do |x|
  x.report("transpose")  { n.times { [a,b].transpose.map(&:max) } }
  x.report("zip")        { n.times { a.zip(b).map(&:max) } }
  x.report("lazy.zip")   { n.times { a.lazy.zip(b).map(&:max).to_a } }
  x.report("loop (max)") { n.times { a.size.times.map{|i| [a[i],b[i]].max} } }
  x.report("loop (>?:)") { n.times { a.size.times.map{|i| a[i]>b[i] ? a[i] : b[i] } } }
end
```

Output

```
                 user     system      total        real
transpose    0.430000   0.000000   0.430000 (  0.428760)
zip          0.420000   0.000000   0.420000 (  0.415070)
lazy.zip     1.010000   0.000000   1.010000 (  1.009173)
loop (max)   0.490000   0.000000   0.490000 (  0.489015)
loop (>?:)   0.150000   0.000000   0.150000 (  0.151461)
```

Comment: But, with `[a,b].transpose` you can't do a lazy enumerator like you can with zip. For large arrays this will create a large number of temporary arrays.

Comment: @stefan can you do benchmark now please? You are expert on that I know :)

Comment: For future reference I just want to note that the info about `zip` wasn't in your answer when I posted mine; your ninja edit doesn't show up in the edit history :-) (just don't want ppl to think I copied)

Comment: @AbeVoelker yeah, SO doesn't track every change, I've added a reference to your post.

Answer (score 7):

```
a.zip(b).map(&:max) # => [3, 5, 11]
```

Comment: Under Ruby 2.0 you might want to do a lazy zip, `a.lazy.zip(b).map(&:max).to_a` for a possible memory gain with enormous arrays (albeit at about a 2x speed decrease)

Answer (score 4):

How is the below ?

*Note:* Size should be equal of both the array.

```
a = [1, 5, 9]
b = [3, 2, 11]

p a.size.times.map{|i| [a[i],b[i]].max}
# >> [3, 5, 11]
```

Or

```
a = [1, 5, 9]
b = [3, 2,11]
p a.size.times.map{|i| a[i]>b[i] ? a[i] : b[i] }
# >> [3, 5, 11]
```

Or,

```
a = [1, 5, 9]
b = [3, 2, 11]

p a.each_index.map{|i| a[i]>b[i] ? a[i] : b[i] }
# >> [3, 5, 11]
```

**Benchmark**

```
require 'benchmark'

iterations = 10_000

a = [1, 5, 9]
b = [3, 2,11]

def stefan(a,b)
  [a, b].transpose.map(&:max)
end

def abe(a,b)
  a.zip(b).map(&:max)
end

def babai1(a,b)
  a.size.times.map{|i| a[i]>b[i] ? a[i] : b[i] }
end

def babai2(a,b)
  a.size.times.map{|i| [a[i],b[i]].max}
end

def babai3(a,b)
  a.each_index.map{|i| a[i]>b[i] ? a[i] : b[i] }
end

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report('Stefan') do
    iterations.times do
      stefan(a,b)
    end
  end

  bm.report('Abe') do
    iterations.times do
      abe(a,b)
    end
  end

  bm.report('babai1') do
    iterations.times do
      babai1(a,b)
    end
  end

  bm.report('babai2') do
    iterations.times do
      babai2(a,b)
    end
  end
  bm.report('babai3') do
    iterations.times do
      babai3(a,b)
    end
  end
end
```

**output**

```
    user     system      total        real
Stefan  0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.046874)
Abe     0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.046873)
babai1  0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.031249)
babai2  0.062000   0.000000   0.062000 (  0.062497)
babai3  0.032000   0.000000   0.032000 (  0.031249)
```